# how to install tensorflow on google cloud platform

Tags: tensorflow, cloud, platform

when I use the command pip install tensorflow the download is only 99% complete and terminated at that point. How can I install tensorflow using google cloud shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing it by yourself you can use the machine learning api and use TensorFlow for training or inference. Just follow this guidelines: https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/training

You can submit a TensorFlow job like this:

```
gcloud beta ml jobs submit training ${JOB_NAME} \
  --package-path=trainer \
  --module-name=trainer.task \
  --staging-bucket="${TRAIN_BUCKET}" \
  --region=us-central1 \
  -- \
  --train_dir="${TRAIN_PATH}/train"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the command on my command prompt but got error.          gcloud beta ml local train C:\Users\divey\cloudml-samples-master\mnist\trainable\trainer=trainer C:\Users\divey\cloudml-samples-master\mnist\trainable\trainer=trainer.task

Comment: you don't have to replace `--package-path=`, you should replace `trainer` And it is the same with the other parameters. Take a look to the link in order to understand it better.

Comment: Ok, I tried this command but got error "import by filename not support".  gcloud beta ml local train --package-path=C:\Users\divey\cloudml-samples-master\mnist\trainable\traine‌​r --module-name=C:\Users\divey\cloudml-samples-master\mnist\trainable\traine‌​r=trainer.task

Comment: have you followed the code of the example? Try with the mnist example: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/mnist/trainable/trainer

Comment: If I were you I would try to replicate the example of the web and the apply modifications over it. You don't seem to understand well how command line options works and probably you are missing more things.